# Any strategies to screen high risk, hopefully high reward stocks?

Tags: risk, investment-strategies

Can't seem to find anything geared towards that. Looking to allocate a small proportion to such stocks.

Comment: It depends what is your frame for 'high risk', for example, if you are considering investing, then high risk stocks would be of firms that may be are well managed but inherently risky due to the nature of the industry e.g. space exploration. On the other hand if you are playing them as trader, the stocks could be penny stocks or general 'trader stocks', in which there are interest for trade only, every exchange has a batch of them.

Answer (score 1):

high volatility,
beta > 1.5,
low volueme

Comment: This answers the original question, but I neglected to include an important part. I'm hoping to get a high reward out of these high risk stocks, that's why I was thinking of strategies.

Answer (score 0):

Determining which stocks might be "high reward" can't be automated/calculated; that depends on evaluating the nature/quality/demand/reliability/etc. of the product and the company. This is gambling, not investing. Do you like the hand you've been dealt? If not, fold and wait for a better one.

Comment: High reward usually entails high risk, but if he understands that and is only risking what he can afford to lose, then it's not a problem.  I don't think investing money in high risk/reward companies should be dismissed as gambling.  But regardless, gambling questions are allowed on the site.

Comment: @pacoverflow: Points granted. It's still something which can't be reduced to a simple rule. Unless you do a LOT of homework before going this route, it's a lot easier to lose than to win. If you want to go this route, I think you need advice MUCH more intensive than Stack Exchange can possibly cover.